# python requests can't find a folder with a certificate when converted to .exe

Tags: python-requests, python-3.5, pyinstaller, facebook-marketing-api

I have a program that pools ad stats from different marketing systems. Everything works fine untill i convert it to the .exe format and run it.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alg\TSK_7. Marketing\report_gui.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    ok = tk.Button(root, text="DO NOT PRESS", bg="red", command=lambda: self.run())
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alg\TSK_7. Marketing\report_gui.py", line 43, in run
    report.merge_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alg\TSK_7. Marketing\process_data.py", line 400, in merge_all
    fb_df     = self.fetch_fb()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alg\TSK_7. Marketing\process_data.py", line 156, in fetch_fb
    fb_campaigns = from_fb.run_fb(self.start_date, self.end_date)  # in JSON format
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alg\TSK_7. Marketing\from_fb.py", line 110, in run_fb
    return s.get_stats()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alg\TSK_7. Marketing\from_fb.py", line 84, in get_stats
    params=params,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\facebookads\adobjects\adaccount.py", line 1551, in get_insights
    return request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\facebookads\api.py", line 653, in execute
    cursor.load_next_page()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\facebookads\api.py", line 797, in load_next_page
    params=self.params,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\facebookads\api.py", line 305, in call
    timeout=self._session.timeout
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 407, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 226, in cert_verify
    "invalid path: {0}".format(cert_loc))
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI253762\facebookads\fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
```

I tried to fix that by using this code but MEI folder keeps changing its digits everytime i run this code so it's no use.

```
dst = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI120642\facebookads'
file = 'fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt'

try:
    os.makedirs(dst);  ## it creates the destination folder
except:
    pass

shutil.move(file, dst)
```

So i went to this file

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py

and tried to comment if statements that raise this error out but got an SSL error. I couldn't find a piece of code responsible for generating those MEI digits.

```
def cert_verify(self, conn, url, verify, cert):
    """Verify a SSL certificate. This method should not be called from user
    code, and is only exposed for use when subclassing the
    :class:`HTTPAdapter <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter>`.

    :param conn: The urllib3 connection object associated with the cert.
    :param url: The requested URL.
    :param verify: Either a boolean, in which case it controls whether we verify
        the server's TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it must be a path
        to a CA bundle to use
    :param cert: The SSL certificate to verify.
    """
    if url.lower().startswith('https') and verify:

        cert_loc = None

        # Allow self-specified cert location.
        if verify is not True:
            cert_loc = verify

        if not cert_loc:
            cert_loc = DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH

        if not cert_loc or not os.path.exists(cert_loc):
            raise IOError("Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, "
                          "invalid path: {0}".format(cert_loc))

        conn.cert_reqs = 'CERT_REQUIRED'

        if not os.path.isdir(cert_loc):
            conn.ca_certs = cert_loc
        else:
            conn.ca_cert_dir = cert_loc
    else:
        conn.cert_reqs = 'CERT_NONE'
        conn.ca_certs = None
        conn.ca_cert_dir = None

    if cert:
        if not isinstance(cert, basestring):
            conn.cert_file = cert[0]
            conn.key_file = cert[1]
        else:
            conn.cert_file = cert
            conn.key_file = None
        if conn.cert_file and not os.path.exists(conn.cert_file):
            raise IOError("Could not find the TLS certificate file, "
                          "invalid path: {0}".format(conn.cert_file))
        if conn.key_file and not os.path.exists(conn.key_file):
            raise IOError("Could not find the TLS key file, "
                          "invalid path: {0}".format(conn.key_file))
```

Comment: I had to put a return statement right at the beginning of the cert_verify() function. That's very dirty and horrible but it worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. It looks like it comes from the certificate bundle `cacert.pem` not being included in the `requests` package directory when the program is compiled. The `requests` module uses the function `certifi.core.where` to determine the location of `cacert.pem`.  Overriding this function and overriding the variables set by this function seems to fix the problem.

I added this code to the beginning of my program:

```
import sys, os


def override_where():
    """ overrides certifi.core.where to return actual location of cacert.pem"""
    # change this to match the location of cacert.pem
    return os.path.abspath("cacert.pem")


# is the program compiled?
if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
    import certifi.core

    os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = override_where()
    certifi.core.where = override_where

    # delay importing until after where() has been replaced
    import requests.utils
    import requests.adapters
    # replace these variables in case these modules were
    # imported before we replaced certifi.core.where
    requests.utils.DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH = override_where()
    requests.adapters.DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH = override_where()
```

Comment: I have looked at many "solutions", but only this works!!! thank you..all other solutions were mis-leading towards corporate proxies and certificates..

Comment: I had the same error but this solution did not work for me. Any help?

Comment: I am getting the same error in databricks but this solution did not work for me . Any suggestions on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by input the following code:

```
import os

import sys

import certifi

os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = 
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), certifi.where())
```

By this I detect the current path to "cacert.pem" and put it in environ

Answer (score 3):

This might be an issue with `requests` package.

I solved this by manually copying the `cacert.pem` file from `/lib/site-packages/certifi` to `/lib/site-packages/requests`

If you want to fix this issue with `.exe`, then copy `cacert.pem` file from `/lib/site-packages/certifi` to `dist/library.zip/certifi/`.

I am considering you have created `exe` using `py2exe`, where `py2exe` will create `library.zip` under `dist/` which contains of all script dependencies. I don't know if other `exe` converters create `library.zip`.

Comment: what if the exe is built without the library.zip?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same problem with the `requests` package when converting to `.exe` with `PyInstaller`. I was developing with conda's virtual environment. I pivoted to using [Python's virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)  (as my colleague had done this and didn't get the same error), installed my packages as usual, created the `.exe` with `PyInstaller` and didn't encounter the same error.

I'm not sure if the `cacert.pem` file is correctly packaged into the `.exe` with the Python virtual environment but is somehow ignored with the conda virtual environment. Perhaps someone else can clarify why this was the case but I hope this helps!

Comment: This solved my problem! I actually did not need to use `venv`; it was sufficient to create an empty `conda` environment and install all of the required packages using `pip` instead of `conda`. Running `PyInstaller` in that environment, `cacert.pem` got bundled correctly.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to disable certificate verification, you can use the `verify=False` parameter in `requests.get()`:

```
requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)
```