# Problem making python program into an exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm

I have been working on a program that shows the weather using python and thought I would try setting it up as an exe for easy installation on other devices. However every time I put in a location to search for using the exe GUI, I get this in the terminal window that opens with the program window:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  File "getWeather.py", line 132, in <lambda>
  File "getWeather.py", line 45, in open_weather
  File "requests\api.py", line 75, in get
  File "requests\api.py", line 61, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 417, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 228, in cert_verify
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Users\pcusername\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI118802\certifi\cacert.pem
```

I have been trying to figure out what the problem is, but haven't been able to find anything to get it working. If anyone can help figure this out I would appreciate it. Also, let me know if any more context/code is needed or if I did anything wrong regarding the post, as it is my first time having to post on stack overflow.

Note, this is using:
windows 11,
python 3.9,
pycharm 2021.2.2,
pyinstaller for exe creation

Comment: What package/library are you using to create your exe?

Comment: I am using pyinstaller to create the exe

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119901/python-requests-cant-find-a-folder-with-a-certificate-when-converted-to-exe

Comment: Doesn't seem to be, throws this: OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Users\rltbv\PycharmProjects\API Weather\dist\cacert.pem, that is if I put it at the beginning of my main py file

Comment: The file `certifi\cacert.pem` is included in the executable generated by `PyInstaller` v4.7 and `requests` v2.27.0 in my Python 3.8.12 in Windows 7.

Comment: The `code`requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)`code` method is doing the same thing as the original.

Comment: Not exactly sure where you are saying your certifi\cacert.pem is, but I don't see one at the location it is checking or in the dist folder with my exe. @acw1668

Comment: The error has shown the location of the file when the executable is being executed.  Check whether the file exists. Also check whether `pyinstaller-hooks-contrib` module is installed.

Comment: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.4 is installed

Comment: Can also confirm there is no certifi folder or cacert.pem file at the file path in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Ok ended up figuring it out:
This method does work: (The top answer) [python requests can't find a folder with a certificate when converted to .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119901/python-requests-cant-find-a-folder-with-a-certificate-when-converted-to-exe)

I was however missing the cacert.pem file still, which gave the error when I tried this fix initially. What ended up working is finding the cacert.pem in the mypycharmproject\venv\Lib\site-packages\certifi folder and then copying it to the dist folder where the exe is located.

Thank you for your help everyone!